# Python: delete main variable from submodule

Tags: python, python-3.x

In IDLE i define variables, seeveral of them. `my1=10; my2=20; my3=300; my4=500;` etc, totally many of them. Now i want to write module `mmm` which can delete all these vars. Can i do it? How to write module `mmm` which can delete these `myNNN` names, so IDLE forgets them.

Comment: From your question, what i understood is `s` is not inside module `mmm` right. So, how can you delete from `s`, but still you can remove from the locals() and globals() namespace using `del`.

Comment: Your question is not clear at all. Please rephrase it. It's hard to understand what you really want to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python, "global" really means "module-level", not "process-level". IOW, your "mmm" module will *not* magically get access to names defined in your "root" module.

Answer (score 0):

you can use 'del'  to delete any variable ,here is an example :

```
import mmm

del mmm.s
```

this code not tested on a modul exampl ,pls test it and replay .

Answer (score 0):

**I am explaining by assuming, you are trying to delete a variable from inside your module 'mmm'**

I ve a module called `mmm`, and i defined `s = 'aa'` inside the module.

```
>>> s = 'aa'
 >>> import mmm
 >>> mmm.s  # variable from module name space
 'aa'
 >>> s      # this is the variable in local name space.
 'aa'
 >>>
```

Lets delete the variable `s` inside module `mmm`:

```
>>> del mmm.s
>>> mmm.s
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 's'
>>>
```

But you can still access the variable define inside local name space:

```
>>> s
'aa'
>>>
```

because it still exists in locals namespace:

```
>>> locals()['s']
'aa'
>>>
```

Now, lets do re-import module `mmm`:

```
>>> reload(mmm)
<module 'mmm' from 'mmm.pyc'>
>>> mmm.s
'aa'
>>>
```

After you re-import module `mmm`, your `mmm.s` is regained.